# Проверка занятости логина

Tags: mysqli, php

Всем привет!

Переделываю скрипт магазина с mysql на mysqli.  Основное всё сделал, но вот с проверкой занятости логина не могу совладеть. Данные пользователя в базу записываются.
Вот код (здесь при регистрации при занятости логина выходит предупреждение):

```
function check_login($user)
    {
        db_connect();

        $query = sprintf(" SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.username = '%s' ",
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($user));

        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) return FALSE;
            else   return TRUE;            
    }
```

Вот новый код (здесь пользователь с таким же логином заносится в бд повторно):

```
function check_login($user)
    {
        global $link;

        $query = sprintf(" SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.username = '%s' ",
                        mysqli_real_escape_string($user));

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) return FALSE;
            else   return TRUE;

    }
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Люди добрые, совсем никак..??

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать как [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119294/). Это будет даже правильнее.

Comment: A1essandro, я читал этот пост, но ничего дельного для себя не взял...    Получается, проверку "check_login" не проходит, и с этим же логином пользователь регистрируется....

Comment: @A1essandro, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.